# Multi calls using 'HttpClient' Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I would like to do a multi call using 'HttpClient'. Something similar that I used to use with axios.

Using axios with Vue:

```
return axios.all([
      axios.get('/friends/name'),
      axios.get('/family/name'),
      axios.get('/collegue/name'),
])
```

Trying with angular:

```
return this.http.all([
      this.http.get('/friends/name'),
      this.http.get('/family/name'),
      this.http.get('/collegue/name'),
])
```

error TS2339: Property 'all' does not exist on type 'HttpClient'

Comment: You should be using forkJoin()

Comment: [here](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **forkJoin** like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {    
    const request1 = this.http.get('/friends/name');
    const request2 = this.http.get('/family/name');
    const request3 = this.http.get('/collegue/name');

    forkJoin([request1, request2, request3]).subscribe(data => {
      this.response1 = data[0];
      this.response2 = data[1];
      this.response3 = data[2];
    });
  }
```

Comment: That is right but why use axios in angular? It also works perfectly with httpClient

Comment: Well I thought axios is the name of his service where http calls are written, had no idea it's a library. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `forkJoin` operator and subscribe to the data as below

```
forkJoin([
  this.http.get('/friends/name'),
  this.http.get('/family/name'),
  this.http.get('/collegue/name'),
 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

When making a request using the `HttpClient`, it will return an rxjs Observable which you will have to subscribe to in order for it to make the request. You should look into one of [these](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/) operators from rxjs, depending on your use case.

You could for example use the [`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) operator like this:

```js
const requests = merge(
    this.http.get('/friends/name'),
    this.http.get('/family/name'),
    this.http.get('/collegue/name')
);
requests.subscribe(console.log); // Executes the requests and logs them as they complete
```